# with something vs by something

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> The transaction was successfully authorised ***with*** the bank

can I substitute with in the sentence with by? If so, does by the bank have any different meaning than with the bank?

Answer (score 1):

A transaction involves at least two parties. Let us assume that they are a bank and a customer.

To say that the transaction was authorised **by** the bank means that the bank approved the transaction with the customer. The customer presumably wished to borrow money and the bank gave its approval to the loan.

To say that the transaction was authorised **with** the bank is somewhat ambiguous. In this instance it is not clear who is doing the authorising. It is possible that some third party, eg. a government body that oversees fair competition, gives the green light to a deal between the bank and the customer. Where company take-overs and mergers are concerned, this is frequently the case.

What is certain is that in this context the two prepositions are not interchangeable.

Comment: This appears just when you are making payment online using a credit card. It seem to tell me that my transaction is done successfully. Can I use by in this case like I described?

Comment: @Young I think it means that the transaction was authorised **by** the bank. But it is also possible that third parties, such as Visa & Mastercard, may be authorising a transaction with the bank. That's to say that these third parties authorise the use of bank credit or debit cards in making a particular purchase.

Answer (score 0):

By the bank signifies the act of authorisation rested solely with the bank and potentially implies you were not involved with the transaction.

With the bank is functionally the same in common usage, but it implies you were involved/aware of the transaction.

Day to day both versions would likely be used interchangeably because the dominant act, that of authorisation, rests with the bank in both cases.